# Client cannot send another message to server

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sockets, client-server, backgroundworker

//====================Solution found================//

Problem : I have a problem whereby my server program cannot acknowledge another message sent from the client .The first one does though . I'm new to c# , therefore i might have less ideas on how best to achieve this .

Current work : Few things I've done so far were sockets in both server and client program , using backgroundworker and delegates .

So here's the scenario :
client program named KipaSusaMati
server program named Asynchronous Server + Mqtt

Server program were run first , then the client . The client supposedly able to send multiple messages to the port without fail,which the server listened to and take those messages and do something(repetitively).

//-----Server coding----//

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (button1.Text == "Start Server")
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("======================================");
            listBox1.Items.Add("Starting server");
            changeServerButton(button1);//mok stop
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(" Stopping server ....");
            changeServerButtonStop(button1);

            try
            {
                if (sListener.Connected)
                {
                    sListener.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Receive);
                    sListener.Close();
                    listBox1.Items.Add(DateTime.Now + " Server Disconnected");
                }
                else {
                    listBox1.Items.Add("Socket not in use . Cannot stop socket .");
                    listBox1.Items.Add(" Press EXIT to exit application. ");
                    button1.Enabled = false;
                    button3.Focus();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

 private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            permission = new SocketPermission(NetworkAccess.Accept,TransportType.Tcp,"localhost",11000);
            sListener = null;
            permission.Demand();
            IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            //IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost");
             IPAddress ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[0];
             ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 11000);
             sListener = new Socket(ipAddr.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
             sListener.Bind(ipEndPoint);
             sListener.Listen(1);
             AsyncCallback aCallback = new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback);
             sListener.BeginAccept(aCallback, sListener);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }

    private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Socket listener = null;
        Socket handler = null;
        try
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);
            handler.NoDelay = false;
            object[] obj = new object[2];
            obj[0] = buffer;
            obj[1] = handler;

            handler.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), obj);
            AsyncCallback aCallBack = new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback);
            listener.BeginAccept(aCallBack, listener);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void ReceiveCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        string stx = "0x02";
        string etx = "0x03";

        try
        {
            object[] obj = new object[2];
            obj = (object[])ar.AsyncState;
            byte[] buffer = (byte[])obj[0];
            handler = (Socket)obj[1];
            string content = string.Empty;
            int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                content += Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0,
                    bytesRead);

                // If message contains "<Client Quit>", finish receiving
                if (content.IndexOf("<Client Quit>") > -1)
                {
                    // Convert byte array to string
                    string str = content.Substring(0, content.LastIndexOf("<Client Quit>"));
                    Console.WriteLine("Bytes from client :"+str);

                    if (content.IndexOf(stx) > -1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("STX were detected");
                    }
                    else {
                        Console.WriteLine("STX were not detected");
                    }


                }
                else
                {
                    // Continues to asynchronously receive data
                    byte[] buffernew = new byte[1024];
                    obj[0] = buffernew;
                    obj[1] = handler;
                    handler.BeginReceive(buffernew, 0, buffernew.Length,
                    SocketFlags.None,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), obj);
                }
                printMessage(content);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

//------Client Coding---------//

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (button1.Text != "BEGIN")
        {
            this.Dispose();
            listBox1.Items.Add(" Disposing and STOP the application");
        }
        else
        groupboxEnableAll();
        listBox1.Items.Add("" + DateTime.Now + " Socket initiated.");
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        button1.Text = "STOP";
    }

 private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);

        try
        {
            SocketPermission permission1 = new SocketPermission(NetworkAccess.Connect, TransportType.Tcp, "localhost", 11000);
            permission1.Demand();
            senderSock = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            senderSock.NoDelay = false;
            senderSock.Connect(localEndPoint);
            Console.WriteLine("SenderSock rawkkkks!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(""+DateTime.Now+" Socket started at port "+port);
    }
```

[client-server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9UZy.png)
From the picture , for the first iteration server managed to get the message sent by client , but for the next iteration , it never displayed .

Solution : Kindly take a look ReceiveCallBack method , instead of doing try catch,im doing do while loop to catch any incoming databytes .

```
        private void ReceiveCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("in ReceiveCallback");

        object[] obj = new object[2];
        obj = (object[])ar.AsyncState;
        byte[] buffer = (byte[])obj[0];
        handler = (Socket)obj[1];
        string content = string.Empty;
        int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

        do
        {
            byte[] buffernew = new byte[1024];
            obj[0] = buffernew;
            obj[1] = handler;
            handler.BeginReceive(buffernew, 0, buffernew.Length,
            SocketFlags.None,
            new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), obj);


        }
        while (bytesRead < 0);

        content += Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0,bytesRead);

        printMessage(content);
}
```

Hope others can benefitting from this .Thanks.

Comment: You should call  handler.BeginReceive in any case even if there is no data available.

Comment: hi @MrgGek , can you be more specific on which part?
I believe I've put it inside my server.ReceiveCallback method , in the 'else' section .

Comment: In the ReceiveCallBack method in the if/else statement you call  handler.BeginReceive() only in the else statement. It means that server stops receiving messages when he is in if condition.

Comment: You send "<Client Quit>" with every message?

Comment: you mean,by default(no data coming in) , the handler should be always called?@MrgGek

Comment: @MrgGek yeah,its some sort sort of 'end-of-line' that I read about .

Comment: Yes, server needs to always listen for connections and messages if it is running. It stops listening only when it shutdowns.

Comment: thanks @MrgGek! now it worked!check out my edited post later . Many thanks to you man.